# How to automatically generate getters and setters inside the controller for the model using MVC pattern

Tags: java, model-view-controller, code-generation

I am currently looking for a way to automatically generate code (may be a code generator) that is compatible with MVC Pattern.

I have seen lots of code generators in the web but they work only for models. They connect it to the database, they generate the model class etc. However, what I am looking for is a tool to create View and Controller classes from the Model class I have written.

### Why I am looking for that?

As you know, in the most common IDEs for java, like Eclipse, IntelliJ etc., there are always a code generator to generate getters and setters of a property and we can use them easily to encapsulate. However , in the controller class, we again need some getters and setters that is in this format:

```
   public void set<ModelName><PropertyName>(<PropertyType> propertyName){
      <modelObject>.set<PropertyName>(<property>);      
   }

   public <PropertyType> get<ModelName><PropertyName>(){
      return <modelObject>.get<PropertyName>();     
   }
```

for example:

```
   Course model;
   public void setCourseId(String id){
      model.setId(id);      
   }

   public String getCourseId(){
      return model.getId();     
   }
```

For these setters and getters, there is no way to automatically generate setters and getters in those IDEs. My aim is to do find such a tool. In another perspective, I want to find a way to automatically generate getters and setters inside a class(controller) for another class(model), instead of writing by hand.

I think frameworks like Spring can have the ability to do this using annotation `@Controller` but I am looking for plain Java, without any frameworks except OSGi.

Comment: tool and such suggestions are off topic for SO, but still. Lombok is a well known way.

Comment: @Stultuske thanks for your advice. I updated my question because It was open to be misunderstood. My real question is to find a way to automatically generate that code. maybe a generator, maybe a native way etc.

Comment: again: there are IDE's that have that functionality, lombok offers that, but I doubt there is something that 'll automagically do that without you selecting anything. After all, what will you do if you have a class for which you don't want setters and getters?
But, again, this is off scope for SO

Comment: Code generators are less flexible than annotation-based processors such as Lombok, because annotation-based  processors are always in sync with whatever is annotated, but generated code, once generated, must be kept manually in sync. The fact that you are looking for "no annotations" is a big red flag for me.

Comment: @tucuxi Actually, I'm not looking for a "no annotations" solution. I just do not want to use any framework except OSGi.

Comment: As it stands, it is not at all clear what you are looking for. What would the view look like? Would calling setCourseId from that view change the course ID immediately? (this would be very innefficient if, say, there are 40 properties that you want to change at the same time, and you have to save the result for *each* of those 40 changes). Please edit the question to describe exactly what you need - and why you think it could be useful for others (the goal of the site is not to solve *your* problems, but rather problems that others may run into, too).